# Azure keeps reimaging my Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, azure

I have a windows server running on Azure that has dependencies on Database and Sync services being installed. Periodically the server seems to be reimaged and the programmes are no longer installed.

Not sure why this happens or how to stop it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are using a Worker or Web role as opposed to a persistant Azure Virtual Machine. Web and Worker roles will always go back to the initial state when recycled.

If you need to make changes to your server configuration you either need to make sure you use a Virtual Machine, or deploy the worker role with logic to install and configure necessary software automatically upon role start.

I hope this helps.